# Using System.js, why do changes I make to a module in one file persist in another?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm

I'm in the beginning of a small web app, and have set it up to use JSPM and System.js for module loading. I have two files, app.js and util.js. In util.js, I am creating a function that gets a Handlebars template for me, and caches them in Handlebars.templates. The actual function has more to it than this, but lets say it just does this

```
import Handlebars from 'handlebars';
export function getTemplate(){ 
    Handlebars.templates = 'HELLO THERE';
}
```

Then, in app.js, I do this

```
import {getTemplate} from 'util.js'
import Handlebars from 'handlebars'
getTemplate();
console.info(Handlebars.templates) //"HELLO THERE"
```

Why does Handlebars.templates persist? Is this something System.js does? Something Handlebars does?

Comment: Never. I think you're implying that "If you never unset it, why shouldn't it persist?", but I'm under the impression that System.js is going into /path/to/handlebars for each import, which (and this is where I'm very uncertain) would pull a fresh copy of the Handlebars module.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? I think this may have to do with some basic understanding of module importing.

Comment: ahh, i misread; you're right, that is weird... if only there was a "real" way to test last-year's ecmaScript we could tell if it's supposed to be like that, or is system.js is janky...

Comment: This behavior is just what I'd expect, you are adding a property on an object, and then using that object somewhere else. It's hard to formulate an answer because I'm not sure why you'd expect this _not_ to work. Imports that resolve to the same module only execute that module a single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 Modules are singletons.  Even though the module is imported by isolated files they both refer to the same instance.  This is the expected behavior and is possible because export and import rely on bindings rather than copying values.

Since you may be coming from a CommonJS background you might find ["What do ES6 modules export?"](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) to be a good explanation about the difference in behavior.